# Format input to currency format using regex

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, format

I want to format an input to a valid currency string, it should format like this:

input `443gr%%g4` output `4434`

input `gg443.4` output `443.40`

input `443,4` output `443.40`

Only `numbers` and `.` are a valid output. And when there is `.` it should have fixed 2 numbers after.

This is my code but it doesn't work correctly:

```
    format(input: any): any {
    if (input === null || input === undefined || input === "") return null;

    const newInput = input
      .toString()
      .replace(/[^\d\.,]/g, "")
      .replace(",", ".")
      .replace(/\./, "x")
      .replace(/\./g, "")
      .replace(/x/, ".")
      .match(/^\d+([\.,]\d{0,2})?/g);

    if (newInput) return newInput[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ").trim();

    return '';
  }
```

Comment: Maybe `.replace(/[^\d.,]+/g,'').replace(/[.,](?![^,.]*$)/g, '').replace(',','.')` will do?

Comment: [Try this](https://regex101.com/r/4jaCkp/1/) - you can then replace comma with a dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const numbers = ['443gr%%g4', 'gg443.4', '443,4', '4.4,3,12344'];
numbers.forEach(x=> 
  console.log(
       x.replace(/[^\d.,]+/g,'').replace(/[.,](?![^,.]*$)/g, '').replace(',','.')
         .replace(/(\.\d{2})\d*$/, '$1')
          .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1 ')
 )
);
```

Here,

- `.replace(/[^\d.,]+/g,'')` - removes all chars but digits, dots and commas
- `.replace(/[.,](?![^,.]*$)/g, '')` - gets rid of all commas and periods that are not final in the string (only last `.` or `,` is kept)
- `.replace(',','.')` - replaces the only `,` with `.` (if present)
- `.replace(/(\.\d{2})\d*$/, '$1')` - removes any fractional digits after first two
- `.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1 ')` - adds spaces as thousand separators.

Comment: this works almost perfectly for me, but how to make second ".replace" to remove every "." besides the first? right now every new "." removes the previous one, could you tell me? I mean only one "." is allowed and every new is removed

Comment: @ChrisK. `.replace(/[.,](?![^,.]*$)/g, '')` really keeps the last one, as I mentioned in the answer. If you need to keep the first one, use `.replace(/^([^.,]*[.,])(.+)$/, function(x,y,z) { return y + z.replace(/[.,]+/g, ''); })`

Comment: yes I need only the first one, works perfectly!